# Swift 3 and Xcode 8 : Get Image From URL Path Stored in SQLITE Database Field

Tags: swift, swift3, sqlite, uiimagepickercontroller

**I have Implemented the Following code to add the image into Document directory and store the Path in my sqlite Database**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        imagePath = imagesDirectoryPath + "/\(Date().description.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")).png"
        print(imagePath)

        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        print(data!)
        let success = FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: imagePath, contents: data, attributes: nil)
        print(success)
        dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in

        }
    }
```

**[Can Anyone help me how to get image back into My Tableview Using this Path as shown in the Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzaig.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Table View **cellForRowAt** Method Or In Ur case if u want to display image in some other Case

You can Simply Do this by

```
let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: student.Image_URL)
cell.imgProfileDisplay.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
```

This will convert the image from the URL that we store in our DataBAse.

For Full Source Code of the Implementation kindly Comment.
Thanks